# Python - axes and plt.figure()

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Could someone look at this code? I must do 3 sample of sinus axes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(311)
y1 = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
ax1.plot(t, y1);
ax1.grid(True)
ax1.set_ylabel('1 Hz');

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(312)
y2 = np.sin(4*np.pi*t)
ax2.plot(t, y2);
ax2.grid(True)
ax2.set_ylabel('4 Hz');

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(313)
y3 = np.sin(6*np.pi*t)
ax3.plot(t, y3);
ax3.grid(True)
ax3.set_ylabel('6 Hz');

plt.show()
```

Could somebody say me why this code do nothing ? I only see "Figure 1" and that's all.

Comment: The code works for me as expected. Perhaps there is something funny with your setup.

Comment: because you only make one figure.  You should see 1 figure with three sub-plots.

Comment: I copied your code into a Windows python (Enthought Canopy) and the three subplots showed up correctly. Check each one individually.

Comment: Yes I want three sub-plots. Even I run one individually I don't see antyhing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `fig.canvas.draw()` before `plt.show()`.

Traditionally `fig.canvas.draw()` does the actual drawing and `plt.show()` enters the interactive event loop. When using IPython or an interactive interpreter,`ion()` and `ioff()` toggle updating after each command.

Interstingly your code does what it should on my computer as well (Debian unstable) - it could be that this behavior changed with newer Matplotlib-Versions.

Comment: Yes now it's ok. Thanks :D